# How to kill inactive user logins on Solaris?

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting, solaris

On a Solaris 10 server if i do a `w`, I get this:

```
12:26pm  up 85 day(s),  1:13,  6 users,  load average: 0.38, 0.36, 0.38
User     tty          login@  idle   JCPU   PCPU  what
blah     pts/1        3Aug15 2days  632:47 632:47  -bash
root     pts/2        4Sep15 6days  201:05  77:59  -bash
blah     pts/3        3Aug15 2days   72:40         -bash
blah     pts/6        13Jul1560days   3:24         -bash
root     pts/22       12:10pm                      bash
root     pts/23       12:17pm                      -bash
```

and when I do `who -all`, I get

```
   .       system boot  Jun 18 11:13
   .       run-level 3  Jun 18 11:14     3      0  S
LOGIN      console      Jul 12 13:54   .     4681
zsmon           .       Jun 18 11:15  old     404
LOGIN      console      Jun 18 11:15   .      876  id=  dt term=0   exit=1      (:0)
ostor    + pts/1        Aug  3 10:35  old   29213       ()
init.css        .       Jun 18 11:16  old    1331  id=  h1
root     + pts/2        Sep  4 08:32  old   13085       ()
ostor   + pts/3        Aug  3 10:41  old   29867       ()
roxa        pts/4        Sep  9 08:45  old    4082  id=ts/4 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/5        Sep  9 09:26  old    4369  id=ts/5 term=0   exit=0
ostor   + pts/6        Jul 13 07:45  old   26750       ()
roxa        pts/7        Sep  9 09:28  old    9010  id=ts/7 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/8        Sep  9 10:11  old    9242  id=ts/8 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/9        Sep  9 10:59  old   16138  id=ts/9 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/10       Sep  9 11:01  old   21040  id=s/10 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/11       Sep  9 11:02  old   21238  id=s/11 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/12       Sep  9 11:19  old   21514  id=s/12 term=0   exit=0
ostor     pts/13       Sep  9 14:29  old   14367  id=s/13 term=0   exit=0
ostor     pts/14       Sep  9 14:58  old   14548  id=s/14 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/15       Sep 10 08:28  old   13820  id=s/15 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/16       Sep 10 10:16  old   14340  id=s/16 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/17       Sep 10 08:40  old   15219  id=s/17 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/18       Sep 10 16:51 20:07  17179  id=s/18 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/19       Sep 10 16:59 19:58  18319  id=s/19 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/20       Sep 11 08:59  3:54   2313  id=s/20 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/21       Sep 11 11:20  1:32  20981  id=s/21 term=0   exit=0
root     + pts/22       Sep 11 12:10   .    28241       ()
roxa        pts/23       Sep 11 12:49  0:10   2623  id=s/23 term=0   exit=0
roxa        pts/24       Sep 11 12:24  0:29    226  id=s/24 term=0   exit=0
```

How do I kill all processes for inactive user roxa?

Comment: Are there stray processes by this roxa user that you're wanting to kill? `ps -U roxa`

Comment: @JeffSchaller The user roxa is attempting to ssh from another server but their connection hangs. Before it times out they kill the putty session leaving those inactive logins above. I tried to kill the sessions using the ID there but I get the message no such process exist.

Comment: so, maybe they have stray sshd processes left? they'd be owned by root, so something like `ps -ef | grep sshd` would get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

If you kill only his sshds, maybe there will processes left which can survive the destruction of their virtual terminal.

If you want a clean way, you can kill all of his processes by the following singleline:

```
for i in `ps uxa|grep ^roxa|sed 's/\+//g'|awk '{print $2}'`;do kill -9 $i;done
```

The essence of this singleline script is between the ``, where a not really complex pipe processes your `ps uxa` output, and extracts his pids out of it.

Comment: @oztalha Thank you very much your fixes! However, such comments as this belong to here, to the "comment" section. Below 50 reputation points you can't create comments, so it is highly advised to get this 50 points ASAP.

Comment: (@oztalha 's text extension converted to a comment): *"Note: I made two fixes to the original answer: (1) pid is the 2nd column, changed $7 to $2; (2) also added the missing closing back-tick (where awk command ends)"*